# center a material design button inside an angular table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got a material design button (second column on screenshot below) inside a mat-cell within an angular table.  The problem is that the button aligns to the right.  How can I get the button to move to the center of the column? I've tried applying layout-align="center center" and fxLayout-align="center-center" on the row (see below), and then also placing similar code within the mat-cell and ng-Container tags with no effect.  Any ideas?  I'd really like to apply it just to the button cell

Thanks

Pete
[image]

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dsUmt" matSort>
 ...
<ng-container matColumnDef="Ticket" >
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Ticket</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let umt" >
        <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="MarkTicket(umt)">
        {{umt.Ticket}}
    </button>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
...
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" layout-align="center center"></mat-row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of a mat-cell you can use `text-align` to align the content. Just add a class to the specific cell and style it accordingly.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tjakmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with the standard angular-material table. As you can see in this case, the symbols are all aligned to the right.